# Regex function matching

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm playing around with regex to learn em a little bit and i came up with a problem i don't understand.

I have this regex

```
\s+(public|private|protected|internal|sealed).*[^{.}]\(.*
```

too match a line of function declaration in c#. But the thing is it works but also matches this line

```
private bool FooBar { get { return _fooBar != null && !_fooBar.BarFoo.Any(); } }
```

I tried to solve it with adding this condition in the regex `[^{.}]` but it keeps matching.
So can someone help me out here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*` you have before your new condition matches all the stuff including the curly braces.

Therefore, you may want something like this:

```
\s+(public|private|protected|internal|sealed)\s+[^{.}]+\(
```

That being said, depending on what you want to do in the end a real parser instead of regular expressions may be more appropriate.

Comment: At least he said he was plying around, not making an enterprise product. When trying to learn regex, anything is a good target for it. Learning why it is a bad idea is also a good idea :-)

Comment: Sure... just trying to rise awareness for when to use (or not) regexes. :)

Comment: Yeah i'm not making a new visual studio :p